# how to access array objects differently and dynamically

Tags: php, web

there is a xml document that i'm parsing to array..
how can i access those array objects and save them in new variables..?
this is piece of php code that is parsing

```
$contents = file_get_contents('test.xml');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($contents);
print_r($xml);
```

here is the xml that is being parsed

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<document>
<txtmsg>
    <smstel>1234567</smstel>
    <smstxt></smstxt>
    <smsdir>Send</smsdir>
    <smstime>06/01/2010 7:54:48 am</smstime>
</txtmsg>
<txtmsg>
    <smstel>33333333</smstel>
    <smstxt>Test sms hhTes12222222</smstxt>
    <smsdir>Send</smsdir>
    <smstime>06/01/2010 7:54:48 am</smstime>
</txtmsg>

<Contacts>
    <conttime>06/01/2010 8:19:05 am</conttime>
        <cnt>
            <fn>Abc</fn>
            <ln>Def</ln>
            <cnttel>123456</cnttel>
            <cntmtel>3333333</cntmtel>
            <cntemail>abc@hotmail.com</cntemail>
        </cnt>
        <cnt>
            <fn>def</fn>
            <ln>ghi</ln>
            <cnttel>234234</cnttel>
            <cntmtel>2424</cntmtel>
            <cntemail>df@hotmail.com</cntemail>
        </cnt>
</Contacts>
</document>
```

and this is output.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [txtmsg] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [smstel] => 1234567 [smstxt] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [smsdir] => Send [smstime] => 06/01/2010 7:54:48 am ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [smstel] => 33333333 [smstxt] => Test sms hhTes12222222 [smsdir] => Send [smstime] => 06/01/2010 7:54:48 am ) ) [Contacts] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [conttime] => 06/01/2010 8:19:05 am [cnt] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [fn] => Abc [ln] => Def [cnttel] => 123456 [cntmtel] => 3333333 [cntemail] => abc@hotmail.com ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [fn] => def [ln] => ghi [cnttel] => 234234 [cntmtel] => 2424 [cntemail] => df@hotmail.com ) ) ) )
```

how can i access each element of xml individually.. like smstel,smstxt,smsdir etc

Comment: I think you should spend some time to see xpath http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp

Comment: @coreCoder Thanks for reffering such a good resource... :) +1 for u

Comment: @Natasha before calling it a "good resource" please visit: http://w3fools.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the best way you can do that..

```
foreach($xml->txtmsg as $txtmsg) {
  echo $txtmsg->smstel;
  // more elements...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm over simplifying it, but *a loop*.

```
foreach($xml->txtmsg as $txtmsg) {
  echo $txtmsg->smstel;
  echo $txtmsg->smstxt;
  // more elements...
}
```

**Note:** When using XML it helps to be aware of the schema. Meaning the above example is specific to those elements you mentioned. Nonetheless, it should help you get started.

Answer (score 2):

Easy

```
(string)$xml->txtmsg->smstel
```

Same goes for params and lists.. its either an object property, or an array

Comment: For the OP's object, this is incorrect. `$xml->txtmsg[0]->smstel` is correct.

Comment: Did you try it? Because I did. PHP 5.3.9 (just in case)

Comment: @jasonMcCreary u are right both solutions are working but your one is that i was looking at

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $xml->txtmsg[0]->smstel; // 1234567
echo $xml->txtmsg[1]->smstel; // 3333333
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$smsTel = (string) $xml->txtmsg[0]->smstel; // 1234567
```

To literally convert the `<txtmsg>` sections to a multidimensional array, you could do:

```
$array = array();
foreach ($xml->txtmsg as $msg) {
  $array[] = array (
    'smstel' => (string) $msg->smstel,
    'smstxt' => (string) $msg->smstxt,
    'smsdir' => (string) $msg->smsdir,
    'smstime' => (string) $msg->smstime
  );
}
print_r($array);

/*
  Array
      (
          [0] => Array
              (
                  [smstel] => 1234567
                  [smstxt] =>
                  [smstel] => Send
                  [smstime] => 06/01/2010 7:54:48 am
              )
          [1] => Array
              (
                  [smstel] => 33333333
                  [smstxt] => Test sms hhTes12222222
                  [smstel] => Send
                  [smstime] => 06/01/2010 7:54:48 am
              )
      )
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the code.
it will be convert you SimpleXML Object to Array

```
function convertXmlObjToArr($obj, &$arr)
{
    $children = $obj->children();
    foreach ($children as $elementName => $node)
    {
        $nextIdx = count($arr);
        $arr[$nextIdx] = array();
        $arr[$nextIdx]['@name'] = strtolower((string)$elementName);
        $arr[$nextIdx]['@attributes'] = array();
        $attributes = $node->attributes();
        foreach ($attributes as $attributeName => $attributeValue)
        {
            $attribName = strtolower(trim((string)$attributeName));
            $attribVal = trim((string)$attributeValue);
            $arr[$nextIdx]['@attributes'][$attribName] = $attribVal;
        }
        $text = (string)$node;
        $text = trim($text);
        if (strlen($text) > 0)
        {
            $arr[$nextIdx]['@text'] = $text;
        }
        $arr[$nextIdx]['@children'] = array();
        convertXmlObjToArr($node, $arr[$nextIdx]['@children']);
    }
    return;
}
```

you will get output in this format

```
Array
(
    @name => books
    @attributes => array ( )
    @children => array
    (
        array
        (
            @name => novel
            @attributes => array ( author => John Doe )
            @children => array
            (
                array ( @name => title, @attributes => array ( ), @text => John's Novel )
            )
        )
    )
)
```